# Hibernate mapping persisted enumerated strings

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have realized I am missing something obvious. Not sure what it is,  Hoping somene an help me see what I am not seeing.

My company starts with mapping files and generates schema and java files.

I am trying to figure out how to map.  I have a table with a column that can have only 1 on a limited number of strings:
      'DOES_NOT_EXIST', 'NEW,INITIATILIZE', 'RUNNING', 'TEARDOWN'

```
TABLE STATE_MACHINE
    ....
    STATE VARCHAR2(32)
.....


public enum StatEnum {
    DOES_NOT_EXIST, NEW,INITIATILIZE, RUNNING, TEARDOWN
}
```

what we want to do is something along the lines of

```
StateMachine machine = new StateMechine();
machine.state=StatEnum.NEW;
....
Persistance.save(machine)
```

Problems is I am receiving "Can't commit transaction: Could not execute JDBC batch update: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BINARY got NUMBER"

I think the HBM mapping file should be something along the lines of 
    
        
            com.foo.StateEnum
            12

Can some point me at some documentation that does what I am trying to do.

Thanks for helping me to learn...

Comment: You'll need to give us more information.  Please show how the StateEnum and the class that uses it are annotated.  Please include only the relevant fields, including the ID fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a class that implements EnhancedUserType and ParameterizedType.

In the package that Implements the above classes I placed my enum class.

my Hibernate xml has

```
    <property name="state" column="state">
        <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
        <meta attribute="field-description">state types</meta>
        <type name="com.....h.core.domain.usertype.MyStrEnumUserType">
            <param name="enumClassname">com.......core.domain.usertype.StateTypeEnum</param>
        </type>
    </property>
```